# Is it possible to restore deleted secure files in azure pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

is there a way how to restore deleted secure file from Azure Devops -> Pipelines -> Library -> Secure Files? I did not find anything but it would be very helpful if there is such option to restore it.

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no build-in feature to restore deleted Secure Files from Library in Azure DevOps.

Check this official doc for details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/secure-files?view=azure-devops

If this is an urgent request by you. You could create a Feature Request via: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion